# Disable drag & drop events in calendar views SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, script, drag-and-drop, js, calendar-view

I want to prevent drag & drop item from calendar view, because I don't want to give editing permission to user directly from calendar view.

Any idea to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it is a hack, but if you can add Modern Script Editor Web Part to the calendar page, you can inject JavaScript, and using that JavaScript you can remove the `drop` event handler on the calendar UI element.